# A very basic JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, calculator

I'm just starting out with code. I created a very basic JavaScript calculator. 
While writing, I couldn't help but think that there must be easier, faster and less redundant ways to write this. For example, when I have to update the display, I have to call the refreshScreen function, which then takes the previous HTML, adds the new stuff to it, and then sets it as the new HTML.

I guess what I'm trying to say is, how can I make the following code less redundant, and are there any libraries that can help me accomplish the same thing in an easier/better/more appreciated way?

It would also be great if I could get some comments on the style of the code. I really want to know what the best coding practices are.

```js
var ans = "0"; // current answer
var pressed = "0"; // keeps track of everything that has been pressed
var resultsScreen = $("#results");
var needsNumber = true; // keeps track of whether or not an operation was selected previously
var allButtons = $("button");
var decimalUsed = false; // makes sure that the user uses the decimal only once

$(document).ready(function(){
    allButtons.on("click", function(){
        var content = $(this).html();
        // special cases
        switch (content) {
            case "=":
                computeAnswer();
                break;
            case "AC":
                pressed = "0";
                break;
            case "CE":
                removeLastPressed();
                break;
            case "Ans":
                if (lastPressedOperation()) {
                    pressed += ans;
                }
                if (pressed == "0") { // if refreshed by pressing AC
                    pressed = ans;
                }
                break;
            default:
                var val = $(this).attr("value");
                console.log("You pressed " + val);
                if (val == null) { // if its an operation
                    if (!lastPressedOperation()) { // if allowed to press operation again
                        pressed += content;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!(val == "." && decimalUsed)) {
                        if (pressed == "0") {
                            pressed = val;
                        } else {
                            pressed += val;
                        }
                        if (val ==".") {
                            decimalUsed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(pressed);
                break;
        }
        refreshDisplay();
    });
});

// post: displays the most current equation or answer
function refreshDisplay(){
    resultsScreen.html(pressed);
    console.log("Your current equation is " + pressed);
}

// post: calculates the answer;
// displays "syntax error" if there is one and alerts the user
function computeAnswer() {
    var val = 0;
    if (lastPressedOperation()) {
        pressed = "Syntax error!";
        refreshDisplay();
        alert("Syntax Error!");
    } else {
        pressed = pressed.replace("x", "*");
        pressed = eval(pressed) + "";
        ans = pressed;
        refreshDisplay();
    }
}

// post: returns true if the last pressed button was an operation; false otherwise
function lastPressedOperation() {
    var lastPressed = pressed.charAt(pressed.length - 1);
    return lastPressed == "x" || lastPressed == "+" || lastPressed == "-" || lastPressed == "/" || lastPressed == "%";
}

// post: removes the last pressed button from the screen and memory
function removeLastPressed() {
    if (pressed.length > 0) {
        pressed = pressed.substring(0, pressed.length - 1); // forget the last pressed button
        if (pressed == "") {
            pressed = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#box {
    background: #005A31;
    position: relative;
    top: 10vh;
    width: 50%;
}

#results {
    background: #CBE32D;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 300%;
}

.buttons {
    background: #A8CD1B;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: hidden;
    border-radius: 20%;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 4%;
}

.buttons:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #CBE32D; !important
}

.buttons:active {
    background: #005A99;
}

.operations {
    background: #F3FAB6;
}

button {
    float: none !important;
}

#row-container{
    text-align: center;
}

#equals {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #092352;
    border-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<html>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="box">
        <h1>JavaScript Calculator</h1>
        <div id="results">0</div>
        <div id="row-container">
            <div class="row">
                <button id="AC" class="buttons col-md-2 operations ">AC</button>
                <button id="CE" class="buttons col-md-2 operations ">CE</button>
                <button id="percent" class="buttons col-md-2 operations ">%</button>
                <button id="subtract" class="buttons operations col-md-3 ">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="7" class="buttons col-md-2 ">7</button>
                <button value="8" class="buttons col-md-2 ">8</button>
                <button value="9" class="buttons col-md-2 ">9</button>
                <button id="multiply" class="buttons operations col-md-3 ">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="4" class="buttons col-md-2 ">4</button>
                <button value="5" class="buttons col-md-2 ">5</button>
                <button value="6" class="buttons col-md-2 ">6</button>
                <button id="divide" class="buttons operations col-md-3 ">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="1" class="buttons col-md-2 ">1</button>
                <button value="2" class="buttons col-md-2 ">2</button>
                <button value="3" class="buttons col-md-2 ">3</button>
                <button id="add" class="buttons operations col-md-3 ">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="." class="buttons col-md-2 ">.</button>
                <button value="0" class="buttons col-md-2 ">0</button>
                <button id="ans" class="buttons col-md-2  operations">Ans</button>
                <button id="equals" class="buttons col-md-3 operations ">=</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLc0st3z/

Comment: You can only use the decimal once, so something like 1.15 + 1.64 will not work, as you cannot add another decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** you should wrap it in this:

```
;(function () {
  'use strict'

  // all your code goes here

}())
```

The `;(function () {  }())` bit is known as an **IIFE** (immediately-invoked function expression). It stops variables from leaking into global scope. This is only a problem in browser JavaScript; in Node.js top-level variables don't leak into global scope.

The `'use strict'` directive tells the engine to run the code in **strict mode**. In a nutshell, strict mode throws more errors, prohibits the dreaded `with` statement, and throws an error if you try to assign to an undeclared variable. It's useful for finding mistyped variables:

```
;(function () {
  let foo = 42
  fooo = 43
  console.log('foo is', foo) // foo is 42
}())

;(function () {
  'use strict'

  let foo = 42
  fooo = 43 // Throws an error
  console.log('foo is', foo)
}())
```

You should use strict mode all the time, in development and production, unless you need a 0.01% edge case where part of your file has to be non-strict. If you use Babel it outputs code in strict mode.

---

HTML structure. The usual way is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
    <title>Blah blah blah</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- main page content goes here -->
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags are optional, so you cam leave them out if you want.

---

```
.buttons:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #CBE32D; !important
}
```

The `!important` goes *before* the semicolon. But try to **avoid** using `!important`, as it can make things messy.

Also, you can set `cursor: pointer` on `.buttons` instead of on `.buttons:hover`. There's no visual difference, except for the specificity of the selectors.

---

```
#equals {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #092352;
    border-width: 7px;
}
```

can be written with the shorthand `border` property:

```
#equals {
    border: 7px solid #092352;
}
```

---

```
return lastPressed == "x" || lastPressed == "+" || lastPressed == "-" || lastPressed == "/" || lastPressed == "%";
```

can be written as:

```
return ["x", "+", "-", "/", "%"].indexOf(lastPressed) > 0
```

or (ES2016 and newer):

```
return ["x", "+", "-", "/", "%"].includes(lastPressed)
```

---

Some people prefer not to indent `switch` statements, so instead of this:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 1:
        doSomething()
        break
    case 2:
        doSomethingElse()
        break
}
```

do this:

```
switch (foo) {
case 1:
    doSomething()
    break
case 2:
    doSomethingElse()
    break
}
```

It can avoid over-indentation. It's just a matter of style.

---

Avoid the `==` operator most of the time, use `===` instead. `==` does loose equality, which means it converts things between different types, and it can do the opposite of what you expect. `===` does strict equality, which means it returns true if the two things are the same (except for `NaN`). It does what you think it'll do.

There is one good reason for using `==`: `foo == null` is a shorter way of writing `foo === null || foo === undefined`.